What does a Lock Screen notification showing the word iPhone and an icon of the phone mean?
This morning, my iPhone 12 (running iOS 18.0.1) showed a strange notification: no message, just an iPhone icon and "iPhone" as text. I can’t expand it even if there’s a dropdown icon in it. I can only clear it.

How can I determine the meaning of this notification?

It seems to be related to AirPlay. Since iOS 18, when I'm playing a song via AirPlay using my iPad, my iPhone lock screen also shows the current song playing (if both devices are connected to the same network).
If I'm clicking on it, I can access the music widget and control the speaker via AirPlay.
For some reason, this other day when the playlist has ended and then the speaker disconnected, my iPhone continued to display the AirPlay notification on my lockscreen but switched back to "iPhone" as output, with no song playing.


